# Using Linq's Where/Select to filter out null and convert the type to non-nullable cannot be made into an extension method

Tags: c#, linq, c#-8.0, nullable-reference-types

Suppose I have

```
List<MyObject?> list = ...;
```

I want to turn it into `List<MyObject>`, but I have not been able to drop the nullable reference.

Below is an MCVE. In my project I have nullable reference warnings turned to errors, so the commented out line below will not compile.

If I do `.Where(e => e != null).Select(e => e!)` then it will be fine in the latest .NET Core 3.1.100, however I cannot extract this into an extension method.

I tried adding this extension method

```
    public static IEnumerable<T> NotNull<T>(this IEnumerable<T> enumerable)
    {
        return enumerable.Where(e => e != null).Select(e => e!);
    }
```

However it will not convert `IEnumerable<MyObject?>` to `IEnumerable<MyObject>` and I am unsure why. This leads me to an error like:

> [CS8619] Nullability of reference types in value of type 'List' doesn't match target type 'List'.

Is there a way I can make the `NotNull` function above work somehow?

Comment: What version of c# are you using? Nullable reference types are allowed in c# 8 + Edit: I know it's in your tag but I want to make sure.

Comment: https://dotnetfiddle.net/cKYl74 Mine compiles.

Comment: @Train .NET Core 3.1 with nullable references and all related things enabled. Mine also compiles but I don't know how to set in the source code to have the nullable warning converted to an error. If I do this in my actual codebase it will compile with the warning as an error. I will add a note above that this is the case, though if you know how to make code warnings as errors via pragmas let me know.

Comment: @Train Well this is interesting, now it works after updating to the latest cutting edge 3.1, but if I try to abstract it in a method it fails, but the where/select combo now work. I will have to edit this question to change it up.

Comment: I've updated the example to make it work, let me look into the warning you asked about. Also you don't need to call .Where...Select, you just need .Where since you're returning the entire object.

Comment: Everything looks fine... restart VS, maybe reboot. Sometimes it's just weird things.

Comment: @Train I am unable to make `Where()` by itself will drop the nullable reference, but `Select` added after it will do the trick and it will build.

Comment: @AustinTFrench Unfortunately I have had no success both

Comment: Sorry I'm having issues reproducing this.

Comment: @Train No worries, I will go make an MCVE from a solution file and post an update with all the files in text format in the opening post when I do. This will further help determine whether I've made a mistake or whether there's something weird on my computer. I'll have to do this after dinner so it may take a bit.

Comment: Sounds great thanks

Comment: @Water please, have a look at my answer below

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a convenient way to filter a sequence of C# 8.0 nullable references, retaining only non-nulls?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58372791/is-there-a-convenient-way-to-filter-a-sequence-of-c-sharp-8-0-nullable-reference)

Answer (score 59, accepted):

You have to update your extension method to the following

```cs
public static IEnumerable<T> NotNull<T>(this IEnumerable<T?> enumerable) where T : class
{
    return enumerable.Where(e => e != null).Select(e => e!);
}
```

The point here is that you are converting the `IEnumerable` of nullable references to not nullable ones, therefore you'll have to use `IEnumerable<T?>`. `where T : class` generic constraint is needed to help the compiler distinguish between nullable reference type and `Nullable<T>` struct, as you can read [here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/try-out-nullable-reference-types/)

> Because of this issue between the concrete representations of nullable
>   reference types and nullable value types, any use of `T?` must also
>   require you to constrain the `T` to be either `class` or `struct`.

After that the following lines will be compiled without any warnings

```cs
var list = new List<MyObject?>();
IEnumerable<MyObject> notNull = list.NotNull();
```

Comment: Unecessary runtime logic to work around a compile time check is..... VERY dirty.

Answer (score 33):

This question is overlaps a lot with [Is there a convenient way to filter a sequence of C# 8.0 nullable references, retaining only non-nulls?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58372791/42921)

[One answer posted there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58373257/42921) exhibited best performance and was extremely consise, with the relevant coding snippet repeated here for posterity:

```cs
public static class Extension {
    public static IEnumerable<T> WhereNotNull<T>(this IEnumerable<T?> o) where T:class
        => o.Where(x => x != null)!;
}
```

Notably; you don't *need* to `Select` just to remove the `?` annotation, and I think it's a pretty reasonable place to place a nullability `!` given that it's pretty clearly correct and likely centralized.  If you really cared about GC perf you might consider caching the delegate in a static readonly field, though whether that's meaningfully faster is something you'd need to measure.

If you prefer a zero-tolerance approach to non-null claims via `!`, then the other answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/59434717/42921 is likely as good as it gets.

Comment: I would change `!= null` to `is not null`

Comment: Can you explain why `.Select()` is not required? It seems like a bug to me. In my understanding, the `!` should enforce non-null on the `IEnumerable<T>`, but not on its elements.

Comment: @TobiasKnauss - yeah, that's unfortunate, isn't it. Nullability analysis isn't like other types; so normal intuitions surrounding it, especially in generic contexts, don't always work. The docs aren't great either, by the looks of it; they only even mention the simple cases.  `!` does not mark something as non-nullable; it "forgives" nullability in the expression entirely, including in generic type parameters.  Note that otherwise, it might even be an error to convert e.g. a `List<string>` into `List<string?>`, not just the other way around.

Comment: @EamonNerbonne, so if I understand correctly, you may add one `!` at the end of an expression and every wrong handling of nullability will be ignored? That's stupid in my opinion, and may produce unnecessary faults. I don't like to forgive nullability on collection elements if I put an `!` at the collection itself. I will try to avoid this usage.

Answer (score 8):

You can use following extensions for Dotnet Core 3.1 both class and struct types.

```
    [Pure]
    public static IEnumerable<T> NotNull<T>(this IEnumerable<T?> enumerable) where T : class
    {
        return enumerable.Where(e => e != null).Select(e => e!);
    }

    [Pure]
    public static IEnumerable<T> NotNull<T>(this IEnumerable<T?> enumerable) where T : struct
    {
        return enumerable.Where(e => e.HasValue).Select(e => e!.Value);
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

If you prefer not to lie to the compiler and do not use the null-forgiving operator, you can solve the issue with `Aggregate` method:

```
static IEnumerable<TSource> WhereNotNull<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource?> source)
{
  return source.Aggregate(
    Enumerable.Empty<TSource>(),
    (accumulator, next) => next == null ? accumulator : accumulator.Append(next));
}
```

Be aware, it is not lazy operation.

If you want lazy operation without the null-forgiving operators, you can use `foreach`:

```
static IEnumerable<TSource> WhereNotNull<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource?> source)
{
  foreach (var element in source)
  {
    if (element != null)
    {
      yield return element;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It can be done without null forgiving operators, using a linq query syntax variant of @ertan answer:

```
    public static IEnumerable<T> WhereNotNull<T>(this IEnumerable<T?> source) where T : class =>
        from item in source
        where item is not null
        select item;

    public static IEnumerable<T> WhereNotNull<T>(this IEnumerable<T?> source) where T : struct =>
        from item in source
        where item.HasValue
        select item.Value;
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative approach would be to make use of `OfType<T>`.

This combines the where and select into a single operation.

```cs
var listOfNullable = new List<MyObject?>();

List<MyObject> result = listOfNullable.OfType<MyObject>();

// as an extension method
public static IEnumerable<T> NotNull<T>(this IEnumerable<T?> enumerable) where T : class
{
    return enumerable.OfType<T>();
}
public static IEnumerable<T> NotNull<T>(this IEnumerable<T?> enumerable) where T : struct
{
    return enumerable.OfType<T>();
}

List<MyObject> result2 = listOfNullable.NotNUll();
```

Note that this does not work for nullable value types like `int?`

Comment: Would this not be a performance killer checking every type for every element compared to the other answers in this thread? Under what conditions would your answer be better than the others? Did you run the code you wrote?