# Filtering for Non-Nullable Strings in C# Lists

Tags: c#, non-nullable, nullability

I'm trying to create a list of non-nullable string values by filtering, but I always end up with a list of nullable strings.

```
var list = new List<string?> {"Cars", "Audi", "", "1920"};
var list2 = list.Where(p => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(p)).ToList(); // return type is List<string?>
```

Can you help me understand why it doesn't return list of non-nullable strings.

Comment: I'm unsure of what you're asking. Are you asking for help on filtering or are you trying to understand what that does?

Comment: [This related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59431558/using-linqs-where-select-to-filter-out-null-and-convert-the-type-to-non-nullabl) may be of interest. The nullability analysis isn't smart enough to do what you're expecting it to do.

Comment: @CharlesMager Well yeah, in addition to this possibility, I found now that it can be done also like this: list.Where(p => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(p)).ToList()!;

Comment: It has nothing to do with being smart enough or not, this is about nullability semantics. As I mentioned below, nullability is independent to the values inside your collection.

Comment: @Blindy it’s an area [the language team are looking to improve](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/blob/main/meetings/working-groups/nullability-improvements/NI-2022-11-01.md#linq). It could conceivably be tracked, as it is in non-linq scenarios.

Comment: You didn't understand the post you linked, it's talking about *selecting* data through an enumerable, which would obviously work. The OP however is constructing a list, which, as I mentioned, can still support null items to be later inserted. There are different semantics at play here.

Comment: @Blindy my understanding is fine, thanks. The selecting _doesn't_ work, there's a warning - that's the point. The proposed change is that nullability would be tracked and the `Where` would return a non-nullable contained type, as was the expectation in this question. The issue [linked at the top of the working group note](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/37468) that prompted the discussion is exactly that. I don't see why you're hung up on it being a list at the end: Any list could have null items added to it later; that doesn't stop you creating a list of non-nullable types.

Answer (score 2):

The type doesn't lose its nullability just because you decided to add only non-`null` items. After all, nothing is stopping you from adding `null`s later.

If you want to change its type, either do it when creating the new list (ie, declare the variable explicitly as `List<string>`), or tell the compiler that the objects your filter returns are non-`null`:

```
list.Where(p => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(p)).Select(p => p!).ToList();
```

Comment: Now that I think about it, it makes perfect sense, thanks for answering!